# Snakemake, how to change output filename when using wildcards

Tags: bioinformatics, snakemake

I think I have a simple problem but I don't how to solve it.

My input folder contains files like this:

```
AAAAA_S1_R1_001.fastq
AAAAA_S1_R2_001.fastq
BBBBB_S2_R1_001.fastq
BBBBB_S2_R2_001.fastq
```

My snakemake code:

```
import glob

samples = [os.path.basename(x) for x in sorted(glob.glob("input/*.fastq"))]
name = []
for x in samples:
    if "_R1_" in x:
        name.append(x.split("_R1_")[0])
NAME = name

rule all:
    input:
        expand("output/{sp}_mapped.bam", sp=NAME),

rule bwa:
    input:
        R1 = "input/{sample}_R1_001.fastq",
        R2 = "input/{sample}_R2_001.fastq"
    output:
        mapped = "output/{sample}_mapped.bam"
    params:
        ref = "refs/AF086833.fa"
    run:
        shell("bwa mem {params.ref} {input.R1} {input.R2} | samtools sort > {output.mapped}")
```

The output file names are:

```
AAAAA_S1_mapped.bam
BBBBB_S2_mapped.bam
```

I want the output file to be:

```
AAAAA_mapped.bam
BBBBB_mapped.bam
```

How can I or change the outputname or rename the files before or after the bwa rule.

Comment: Try the following in a python interactive interpreter: `"AAAAA_S1_R1_001.fastq".split("_R1_")`. You'll see that the "_S1" is included in the first word of the resulting list. Since this is how you build your `NAME` list of sample names, those "_S1" parts stay in your `sample` wildcard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pathlib

indir = pathlib.Path("input")
paths = indir.glob("*_S?_R?_001.fastq")
samples = set([x.stem.split("_")[0] for x in paths])

rule all:
    input:
        expand("output/{sample}_mapped.bam", sample=samples)


def find_fastqs(wildcards):
    fastqs = [str(x) for x in indir.glob(f"{wildcards.sample}_*.fastq")]
    return sorted(fastqs)


rule bwa:
    input:
        fastqs = find_fastqs
    output:
        mapped = "output/{sample}_mapped.bam"
    params:
        ref = "refs/AF086833.fa"
    shell:
        "bwa mem {params.ref} {input.fastqs} | samtools sort > {output.mapped}"
```

Uses an input function to find the correct samples for `rule bwa`. There might be a more elegant solution, but I can't see it right now. I think this should work, though.

*(Edited to reflect OP's edit.)*

Comment: Thank you very much! I only need to change my question. it is not always "_S1_". I updated my question.

Comment: Amazing it works, now I need to figure out what all the code means =) Thanks!

Comment: @BioFrank This solution builds a "correct" list of sample names: by splitting on `"_"`, it excludes the  `"_S*"` part. Then, it uses a function as input. This enables determining the input file name in a more complex manner than just substituting wildcards in a string. In this case, it uses `glob` in order to find all fastq files starting with the desired wildcards. This solution might fail if you have sample names including `"_"` or if you have other files in the `input` folder that start with the sample name and a `"_"` and that end in `".fastq"`.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I've also had this problem with filenames with the following logic: `{batch}/{seq_run}_{index}_{flowcell}_{lane}_{read_orientation}.fastq.gz`.

I think that the core problem is that none of the individual wildcards are unique. Also, not all values for all wildcards can be combined; seq_run1 was run on lane1, not lane2. Therefore, expand() does not work.

After multiple attempts in Snakemake (see below), **my solution was to standardize input with `mv` / `sed` / `rename`**. Removing `{batch}`, `{flowcell}` and `{lane}` made it possible to use `{sample}`, a unique combination of `{seq_run}` and `{index}`.

---

What did *not* work (but it could be worth to try for others in the same situation):

- [Adding the zip argument to expand()](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#the-expand-function)
- Renaming `output` using the following syntax: 
  `output: "_".join(re.split("[/_]", "{full_filename}")[1,2]+".fastq.gz"`