# Snakemake use part of input file name for the output

Tags: python, alignment, snakemake, fastq

I have multiple datafiles in a .fastq format with names like

start-Number_NAME-Sample_info-Machine_info-Lab_info-end_R1.fastq.gz (and a similar with R2) So two examples could be

start-1000_John-brain_1-hiseq_2500-LAB_KA-end_R1.fastq.gz 
start-1000_John-brain_1-hiseq_2500-LAB_KA-end_R2.fastq.gz

start-1200_Smith-Liver_5-Novaseq_6000-LAB_RH-end_R1.fastq.gz 
start-1200_Smith-Liver_5-Novaseq_6000-LAB_RH-end_R2.fastq.gz

They all have the same structure however, they all vary in the number, name, sample, Machine and lab info, which makes it hard for me to make a snakemake rule covering all of them.

My goal is to use a tool on these input files, such as alignment with bwa mem. However I would like to create a short output name. Such that the input file would be the full name and the output name would only contain Number_NAME info, so I can create files like 1000_John.bam and 1200_Smith.bam

I am using Snakemake to create this pipeline, and i have tried multiple things but cannot get it to work.

---

First option:
with this link ([Snakemake, how to change output filename when using wildcards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58780883/snakemake-how-to-change-output-filename-when-using-wildcards))

```
import pathlib
import glob
import os
indir = pathlib.Path("FASTQ/chr1/")
paths = indir.glob("start-*R?.fastq.gz")
SAMPLES = set([x.stem.split("-")[1] for x in paths]) # ID's
print(SAMPLES)

rule all:
    input:
        expand("output/{sample}_mapped.bam",sample=SAMPLES)

def find_fastq(wildcards):
    fastqs = [str(x) for x in indir.glob(f"{wildcards.sample}*.fastq.gz")]
    return sorted(fastqs)

rule bwa:
    input:
        fastqs = find_fastq
    output:
        mapped = "output/{sample}_mapped.bam"
    params:
        ref = "ref.fa"
    shell:
        "bwa mem {params.ref} {input.fastqs} {input.fastqs} | samtools sort > {output.mapped}"
```

i get the correct set of Number_NAME id, but the bwa rule gives me

> Error in rule bwa:
> jobid: 54
> output: output/1000_John_mapped.bam
> shell:
> bwa mem ref.fa | samtools sort > output/1000_John_mapped.bam
> (one of the commands exited with non-zero exit code; note that snakemake uses bash strict mode!)

So the fastq are not given as input to the bwa mem command. and i have tried several different iterations with the paths (using * or ?) and list comprehension of the SAMPLES.

I've also tried creating two find_fastq functions for both R1 and R2 but it doesn't work. and even if i only parse one file to bwa mem it should still run as single-end alignment, so with bwa mem {params.ref} {input.fastqs}

---

Second option:

I've also tried to simply create two seperate list containing the ID =["1000_John","1200_Smith"] and the INFO = ["brain_1-hiseq_2500-LAB_KA-","Liver_5-Novaseq_6000-LAB_RH"] but then if i use expand in my bwa rule

```
f1 = expand("start-{sample}_{info}-end_R1.fastq.gz",sample=ID,info=INFO),
f2 = expand("start-{sample}_{info}-end_R2.fastq.gz",sample=ID,info=INFO)
```

it fails because the expand are the products of the two sets. and not just the comparison of the same index across two list. SetA = ["A","B"] SetB = ["C","D"] -> expand AC, AD, BC, BD, what i want is AC and BD.

---

Third option:
Creating a list containing all the different information and then just parse the sliced info to the expand function.

```
fastqdir = glob.glob('FASTQ/chr1/'+'*_R1.fastq.gz')
print(fastqdir)
SAMPLES = [i.split("-",2) for i in fastqdir] 
SAMPLES = [item for sublist in SAMPLES for item in sublist] #creating a list with all elements
#['start','1000_John','brain_1-hiseq_2500-LAB_KA-end_R1.fastq.gz','start','1200_Smith','Liver_5-Novaseq_6000-LAB_RH-end_R1.fastq.gz']
print(SAMPLES[1::3]) #all ID's

f1 = expand("start-{sample}_{info}",sample=SAMPLES[1::3],info=SAMPLES[2::3]),
f2 = expand("start-{sample}_{info}",sample=SAMPLES[1::3],info=SAMPLES[2::3])
```

But again that didn't work either.

QA:

- Are there any way to just do the pairwise comparison between the elements in the same index of two lists using the expand function instead of the product?
- Or can anyone help with the first option using path and how to properly use this idea of renaming while giving the full name as input.
  Other suggestions are also appreciated

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to solve such an issue.
Your second approach is not far off, except that `expand()` uses the itertools function `product` and hence produces all combinations of your two wildcard lists. You can however make it to use `zip` instead, which will give you the desired combinations (see here: https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#the-expand-function). That would be:

```
expand("start-{sample}_{info}-end_R1.fastq.gz", zip, sample=ID,info=INFO)
```

I would suggest thinking about a samplesheet here. You can design a simple tsv file which has one column with your desired sample name and another (two) column(s) which contain the exact path and name of the fastq file(s).
This sheet can be read in the Snakefile as let's say a pandas dataframe and allows you to get the fastq file for every sample with the use of an input function.

This option also allows you to easily add new samples to the experiment without updating any lists in the Snakefile.